# TImoutexception with Guava cache + Spring Data + Couchbase indexed document

Tags: spring-data, guava, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

**General Architecture:** I have a Guava Cache class that should hold the results of some data that is stored in Couchbase.

The access to the document is with Spring Data, and there is an index on the requested document, so it is returning very very fast, usually in few milliseconds.

**The problem:** In the first time after the Spring Boot app is restarted, the access to the Spring Data repository is getting `TimoutException`. Yet it works as expected on the 2nd request and after that, till the next restart of the app.

Cache class:

```
private final CatsRepository catsRepository;
private LoadingCache<String, Map<String, Integer>> catsAsMapCache;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    catsAsMapCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(1000)
            .expireAfterWrite(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build(
                    new CacheLoader<String, Map<String, Integer>>(){
                        public Map<String, Integer> load(String key){
                            Cat cat = catsRepository.findFirstByCatId(key);
                            // do some cool stuff here and return a map
                        }
                    }
            );
}
```

When the `findFirstByCatId(...)` is called for the first time it will always get `Timeoutexception`. But from the 2nd call and after that, it works perfectly.

**The exception:**

`com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all of the details, but I do know that Spring Data initializes libraries for accessing Couchbase in a way that does not block the rest of the loading, intentionally.  I am guessing this may have something to do with the initial timeout, since the first request may go through while there's a lot going on at once.

One option, is there a way to complete a `bucket.ping()` against the cluster before servicing regular requests?  This feature is intended as a health check of sorts, and would ensure all of the connections are built, etc.  This might be done in initialization or using actuator.